# Am I putting too much in my NSMutableArray? Please help!

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimageview, size, nsmutablearray

So I am making an app really quick, and even though it isn't the best solution, it appears to be working for the most part. So I have a simple image view that pulls an image out of an NSMutableArray arr. I create the array and populate it inside of ViewDidLoad in this manner:

```
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"181940jpg"]];
[arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"168026.jpg"]];
[arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"168396.jpg"]];
[arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"168493_.jpg"]];
```

ANd I continue doing that for 130 images. Obviously this is a big array. I don't know if this is like a really bad way to do it, but if it is, I am open to suggestions! As I go through the array with some simple back and forward buttons pulling images out of the array based on a simple counter variable things work ok until image 45-ish. The app breaks down and the console says this:

*** ERROR: ImageIO 'ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback' header is not a CFDictionary...

Would it help if I broke my images up into separate arrays? Am I just putting too much into the array? What am I missing here, trust me, I am all ears.

Thanks

EDIT:  Here is some more information

This is how I am sifting through the array, using a UISegmentedControl set on the top of the screen:

```
  -(void) pickedOne{
if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    NSLog(@"hey");
    if(position < [arr count]-1){

        position++;//This is my global counter variable
        UIImage * img = [arr objectAtIndex:position];
        [imageView setImage:img];
        [img release];
    }       

}else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==0){

    if(position >0){

        position--;
        UIImage * img = [arr objectAtIndex:position];
        [imageView setImage:img];
        [img release];
    }       

}
  }
```

It doesn't appear to be a problem with memory management, but then again, I don't consider myself a pro at that by any means...

Comment: I think you'll need to give more details on your implementation. be definition an NSMutable won't be too small since it doesn't have a predefined size. I think your issue is more on how your accessing and releasing the values. if you manage to create your array then its not too big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of the mutable array, what you put into it is just a pointer to some other object.  It is those other objects you have to worry about and, yes, you have too many of them (more likely than not).

> - ERROR: ImageIO 'ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback'
>     header is not a CFDictionary...
>
> Would it help if I broke my images up
>   into separate arrays? Am I just
>   putting too much into the array? What
>   am I missing here, trust me, I am all
>   ears.

That sounds more like you have an over-release problem and are passing something bogus to the ImageIO APIs.

And, in fact, that is exactly what you have:

```
    UIImage * img = [arr objectAtIndex:position];
    [imageView setImage:img];
    [img release];
```

That `release` is spurious;  it does not balance a retain anywhere in your code.   `objectAtIndex:` does not return a retained object and the `UIView` will take care of retaining/releasing the image internally.

Remove that `release` (and the other one, too)!

You still need to worry about memory consumption.   At a size of 42K each (not an unreasonable size, but entirely made up), 130 images will weigh in at ~6MB or so, prior to any decompression or other expansion that occurs as a part of storage.

The devices are quite memory constrained.